# Woocommerce fatal error : error in single-product template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My site is broken and below is the displayed message.
When I deactivate Woocommerce, erveything runs well, but I need it activated.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function is_on_sale() on null in /home/brga7543/smatchcard.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/sale-flash.php:25 Stack trace: #0 /home/brga7543/smatchcard.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(345): include() #1 /home/brga7543/smatchcard.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php(1676): wc_get_template('single-product/...') #2 /home/brga7543/smatchcard.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash('') #3 /home/brga7543/smatchcard.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #4 /home/brga7543/smatchcard.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5 /home/brga7543/smatchcard.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php(43): do_action('woocommerce_bef...') #6 /home/brga7543/smatchcard.com/wp-includes/template.php(772): require('/home/brga7543/...') #7 /home/brga7543/smatchcard.com/wp-content/plugins/wo in /home/brga7543/smatchcard.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/sale-flash.php on line 25

Comment: Is your Woocommerce is up to date ?
Seems your problem is related to your theme and not Woocommerce. 
Try to switch your theme with a standard theme like twenty-two and see whats going on.
If it doesn't work, try to disabled plugin one by one.

Comment: What actions have you performed before the error appeared ? Deactivate the theme or other plugins that may conflict. Perhaps you tried to override/change woocommerce templates ?

Comment: This issue occures when child-theme is activated.
When I deactivate it, everything runs well.
When child-theme is activated, If I deactivate Woocommerce, everything runs well.